# MUI Dialog inside a ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup() not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, modal-dialog, server-side-rendering

I am using the DIALOG component for the first time and thought it work seamlessly in my setup. Unfortunately it DID NOT and after breaking my head for a long time I suspect its because of ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup() that I am using.

I am trying to use a MUI Dialog inside the JSX returned by ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup().

Though I am not rendering this in the server side I am doing this because the @types/d3-org-chart requires the return type to be a string for nodeContent function. Everything was working till now till I added a  inside nodeContent. Now when I click on the  I expect a dialog box to open up and display the data. Instead it just throws this warning in the console and does NOTHING. I am suspecting this might be due to my conversion of JSX to string using ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(). Is it that MUI Dialog/Modal do NOT work in SSR? Is there a way to create a Dialog in my scenario or should I NOT use ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup() to convert it to a string?

**Warning in Browser Console:**

```js
Clicked on this button with event [object PointerEvent] data data,height,depth,parent,id,children,width,x0,y0,firstCompact,compactEven,flexCompactDim,firstCompactNode,x,y
Clicked on this button with event [object PointerEvent] data [object Object],150,0,,ST-33,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],375,0,0,,,,,0,0
Clicked on this button with event [object PointerEvent] data ST-33
Clicked on this button with event [object PointerEvent] data 12

Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output format. This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client. See https://reactjs.org/link/uselayouteffect-ssr for common fixes.
    at ButtonBase (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8585:22)
    at WithStyles (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25770:31)
    at Button (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8342:24)
    at WithStyles (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25770:31)
    at div
    at FullScreenDialog (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2626:19)
    at div
    at div
    at div
Open variable is changed and is set to true
```

**Code Snippet:**

```js
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';
import { TransitionProps  } from '@material-ui/core/transitions';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

export const InternalDirectoryStructure = (props: InternalStructProps) => {
  const d3Container = useRef(null);
  //let chart = null;
  let [chart, setChart] = React.useState(new OrgChart<UserData>());


  const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
  };

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
      console.log(`Open variable is changed and is set to ${open}`)
  }, [open]);

   chart
    .nodeContent(function (d: any, i, arr, state) {
            let nodeColor = '#904C3F';

            const nodeStyling: CSS.Properties = {
                fontFamily : 'arial',
                backgroundColor : nodeColor,
                position:   'absolute',
                marginTop : '-1px',
                marginLeft: '-1px',
                width: `${d.width}px`,
                height: `${d.height}px`,
                borderRadius: '10px',
            }
            const nodeReporteeStyling: CSS.Properties = {
                color: '#ffffff',
                marginRight:   '30px',
                marginTop: '15px',
                textAlign: 'right',
            }
            const nodeCenterContentStyling: CSS.Properties = {
                padding: '20px',
                paddingTop: '5px',
                textAlign: 'center',
            }
            const nodeNameStyling: CSS.Properties = {
                color: '#ffffff',
                fontSize: '24px',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
            }
            const nodePositionNameStyling: CSS.Properties = {
                color: '#ffffff',
                fontSize: '24px',
                marginTop : '4px',
            }
            const nodeLineStyling: CSS.Properties = {
                borderBottom : '1px solid white',
            }

                return ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(
                    <div style={nodeStyling}>
                        <div style={nodeReporteeStyling}>
                            <Badge className={'reportees'} badgeContent={d.data.reporteeCount} color="primary">
                                <PeopleIcon/>
                            </Badge>
                            <Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose} TransitionComponent={Transition}>
                                <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose} aria-label="close">
                                    <CloseIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                                <DialogContent>
                                    Hello
                                </DialogContent>
                            </Dialog>
                        </div>

                        <div style={nodeCenterContentStyling}>
                            <div style={nodeNameStyling}> {d.data.displayFeName}</div>
                            <div style={nodePositionNameStyling}> {d.data.displayFeLabel || ''} </div>
                            <br/>
                            <div style={nodeLineStyling}> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
        })
         .nodeUpdate(function (d: any) {
            select(this)
            .select('.node-rect')
            .attr('stroke', (d: any) =>
              d.data._highlighted || d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted
                ? '#FFFFFF'
                : 'none'
            )
            .attr(
              'stroke-width',
              d.data._highlighted || d.data._upToTheRootHighlighted ? 15 : 1
            );
            select(this).on('click.node-update',(event,data: any)=>{
                  if ([...event.srcElement.classList].includes("node-button-foreign-object")) {
                       chart.clearHighlighting();
                       chart.setUpToTheRootHighlighted(data.id).render();
                  }
            });
            select(this)
            .select('.reportees').on('click',(event,d: any)=>{
                console.log(`Clicked on this button with event ${event} data ${Object.keys(d)}`)
                console.log(`Clicked on this button with event ${event} data ${Object.values(d)}`)
                console.log(`Clicked on this button with event ${event} data ${d.id}`)
                console.log(`Clicked on this button with event ${event} data ${d.data.reporteeCount}`)
                setOpen(true)
            })
        })
        .onNodeClick(function (d:any) {
            chart.clearHighlighting();
            chart.setUpToTheRootHighlighted(d).render();
            //If Node has some reportee count then we need to display the reportee contact
            let nodeData:UserData =  props.data.find((obj:UserData) => obj.id === d);
        })
       .render().fit();

        select(d3Container.current).style(
          'background-color', '#333333',
        )
}, [props.data, d3Container.current]);
```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example of `InternalDirectoryStructure`? I want to see how your are integrating chart with the Dialog

Comment: I have finally got it to work!! The place where I had the Dialog in the DOM was causing the issue. I changed the place where the Dialog is placed in the DOM and it works now..  I have referred to this link and changed my code accordingly and now the modal seems to pop up. https://github.com/bumbeishvili/org-chart/issues/125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on the internet, there are two solutions you can try:

1. try `renderToString()` instead of `renderToStaticMarkup()`. However, I noticed that you are not using any SSR.
2. It seems to be the issue with when components are rendered inside the event loop with `useLayoutEffect`. Same errors are reported from people using antd + next.js and react + antd, from this github issue : https://gist.github.com/gaearon/e7d97cdf38a2907924ea12e4ebdf3c85?permalink_comment_id=3672883#gistcomment-3672883

Adding this package `useIsomorphicLayoutEffect` might fix your issue.

You can download this package: `npm i use-isomorphic-layout-effect`

Check out this markdown page for more info on the package: https://gist.github.com/gaearon/e7d97cdf38a2907924ea12e4ebdf3c85?permalink_comment_id=3318852#gistcomment-3318852

Comment: Thanks for your time. I agree that I am NOT doing SSR but I am using ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup() which maybe is causing the browser to think its a ssr. I replaced renderToStaticMarkup() with renderToString() but that did NOT help. I have replaced useLayoutEffect() with useEffect() but that does'nt help either. The links that you have suggested is making us check if its SSR by using the window object and then use useEffect(). But I just replaced all useLayoutEffect() of that component with useEffect() and it still complaining.

Comment: For others its just that the warning is annoying. But for me the Modal itself is NOT popping up and the only thing i notice is the warning.  Wondering if there is a way to convert my JSX to string without calling any API's from the ReactDOMServer which I feel is causing the issue. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: I have finally got it to work!! The place where I had the Dialog in the DOM was causing the issue. I changed the place where the Dialog is placed in the DOM and it works now.. Thanks for your answer with regards to the warnings!!

Comment: @Pradeep Great! It's nice to know.